# Overload type parameter in Java class definition

Tags: java, generics, types, overloading

Suppose I have a java class

```
public class Foo<ELEMENT, COMPARATOR extends Comparator<ELEMENT>> {
    public Foo(ELEMENT e, COMPARATOR c) {...}
}
```

How can I reload the type parameter `<ELEMENT>` so that I can also have something like

```
public class Foo<ELEMENT extends Comparable> {
    public Foo(ELEMENT e) {
       this(e, new Comparator<ELEMENT>() {
           public int compare(ELEMENT e1, ELEMENT e2) {
              return e1.compareTo(e2);
           }
       })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't, basically.  (`TreeSet` is an example of a class that would do it if it could.)

One thing you can do, on the other hand, is use static factory methods instead of public constructors.  For example, you can write

```
public class Foo<E> {
  public static <E> Foo<E> withComparator(E e, Comparator<? super E> comparator){
    ...
  }
  public static <E extends Comparable> Foo<E> withoutComparator(E e) {
    ...
  }
}
```

This allows you to put different type constraints on different factory methods, e.g. adding a `Comparable` constraint on the overload that doesn't take a `Comparator`.

Comment: In your solution the type parameter `COMPARATOR` is removed from class definition, what if I want to keep that parameter?

Comment: Can you explain what you're doing, that the comparator should be a type rather than an object?  That doesn't usually make sense with comparators.

Comment: Well, I want to create a generic Range concept, which has a bounds (to, from), a comparator to determine the order of elements in the range, and a Step calculator determine how to move among elements. A range can be merged with another range of the same type (same element type, same comparator type and same step calculator type). Thus comparator type needs to be added into the class type parameters. I have that generic range defined and it works good, but I want to create a simple range with only element type parameter and   comparator type, step calculator type should be default to something

Comment: BTW, the comparator is the Range is defined as a generic function: `interface Func2<P1, P2, R> {R apply(P1 p1, P2 p2);}`

Comment: That's...tricky.  Assuming you have a default `Comparator` type -- which you would need -- you could have a method `<E, C extends Comparator<E>> Foo<E, C> create(E, C)` and a method `<E extends Comparable> Foo<E, NaturalComparator<E>> create(E)`.  But TBH, I don't think you're going to be able to shoehorn everything you're hoping to into the Java type system.  (Certainly many external types aren't going to expose `Comparator` types; they'll expose `Comparator` _objects_, like `String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER`.)